# Serilog to log method start and received parameter values

Tags: c#, serilog

I have the following concrete Serilog helper class ine a .Net 4.6.2 WPF app:

```
public SerilogHelper()
    {
        Logger = CreateLogger();
    }

    private  ILogger CreateLogger()
    {

        string levelString = Properties.Settings.Default.SerilogLevel;

        SerilogLevel level = (SerilogLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(SerilogLevel), levelString);

        var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
        levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = (Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel)level;

        string acName = Properties.Settings.Default.LoggingAccountName;
        string acKey = Properties.Settings.Default.LoggingAccountKey;

        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials creds = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(acName, acKey);
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount azureAccount = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount(creds, true);

        return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
            .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
            .WriteTo.AzureTableStorage(azureAccount)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
```

With things setup, I call helper methods such as the following:

```
public  void WriteString(string content)
{
    Logger.Debug(content);
}
```

I'd like to create a method to log that a method has started, its name and the values of any parameters. So, the calling method would look something like:

```
SerilogHelper.StartingMethod("My method name", params for my method)
```

Is there a neat way of doing this?

Comment: Your string that you pass to Serilog should *not* be anything except a constant value. Make sure you read [the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events).

Comment: You may still have to enumerate all parameters. Call to the logging function would look like this: WriteString(nameof(MyFunction), param1, param2, param3) and declaration would  be WriteString(string functionName, params object[] data).